# Getting invalid argument passed error when trying to preg_replace $1 variable

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is the code Im getting the error on:

```
$show_nav = preg_replace('#\{\$SUBMENU([0-9]+)\}#',implode("\n",$sub_menu['submenu$1']),$show_nav);
```

So basically I want to replace a string within the $show_nav variable such as {$SUBMENU2} with data from the sub menu array. I tested and it works just fine if I manually put in the number like so:

```
$show_nav = preg_replace('#\{\$SUBMENU([0-9]+)\}#',implode("\n",$sub_menu['submenu2']),$show_nav);
```

I also verified the regex is grabbing the proper variable by doing this:

```
$show_nav = preg_replace('#\{\$SUBMENU([0-9]+)\}#','$1',$show_nav);
```

It replaces the string with what is found in the {$SUBMENU} string. So if its {$SUBMENU3} it gives me back 3, {$SUBMENU5} it gives me back 5. But I cant seem to get it to dynamically read the $1 variable. I tried adding curly brackets, still same error:

```
$show_nav = preg_replace('#\{\$SUBMENU([0-9]+)\}#',implode("\n",$sub_menu['submenu{$1}']),$show_nav);
```

or:

```
$show_nav = preg_replace('#\{\$SUBMENU([0-9]+)\}#',implode("\n",$sub_menu['{submenu$1}']),$show_nav);
```

I know Im entering it wrong, but cant figure out the proper way of doing it. Any suggestions?

****UPDATE****
Thanks for the suggestions provided by Toto and Wiktor Stribiżew this is the code that resolved my issue, thanks again!!!

```
$show_nav = preg_replace_callback(
'#\{\$SUBMENU([0-9]+)\}#',
function($m) use($sub_menu) {

if(isset($sub_menu['submenu' .$m[1]]))
                                        {
return '<ul class="nav-dropdown">' .implode("\n",$sub_menu['submenu' .$m[1]]) .'</ul>';

}

},$show_nav);
```

Comment: You need a `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is your friend:

```
$show_nav = preg_replace_callback(
            '#\{\$SUBMENU([0-9]+)\}#',
            function($m) use($sub_menu) {
                  return implode("\n",$sub_menu['submenu'.$m[$1]])
            },
            $show_nav);
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Will accept your answer when it lets me, thanks again!